# PHPでプログラミングの宿題

Tags: php

PHPの宿題で分からないことがあるので教えて下さい。

> 配列 `array("He", "is", "a fat man")` を、 `array("He", "is", "a", "fat", "man")`
>   に変換するような関数 lens() を実装しなさい。

私の書いたコードは

```
<?php
function lens(array $arr) {
    $tmp1 = array_pop($arr);
    $tmp2 = explode(" ", $tmp1);
    $result = array_merge($arr, $tmp2);
    return $result;
}

$before = array("He", "is", "a fat man");
$after = lens($before);
print_r($after);
```

こんな感じです。これでもだいぶ短くしたつもりだったのですが、先生が言うには、これでもまだ長すぎで、関数の中をもっとシンプルにできるとのこと。
関数を2つ使うだけで出来るらしいのですが、どうすれば良いのか見当もつかないので教えてください。

提出期限は明日（日曜）の午前中なので、どうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 最後の要素だけ`explode`する仕様？、`array("He is", "a fat man")`も受け付けるべきなのでは？

Comment: 宿題ということなので答えそのものは書きませんがimplode()が鍵です

Comment: まだ時間があるので僕も答え自体は書きませんが、配列結合のimplodeとexplodeを使うと実現出来るかと。
処理的には無駄な処理が入りますが、
一度全体を処理しやすい形に加工→一気に同じ加工をしてreturn　という処理の仕方ならシンプルに書けますよ。

Comment: `array("He", "is", "a  fat man");` などのスペースが複数入る場合を考えると `explode` よりは `preg_slice` の方が良いかも。

Answer (score 2):

マウスカーソルを合わせると表示されます。
必ず自分で考えた上で閲覧する事をオススメします。

- ヒント１

  > 分割するべき文字列は半角の空白で区切られている
- ヒント２

  > 既に配列になっているのであれば、一度結合し文字列にすることで扱いやすくなる
- ヒント３

  > `implode(結合文字, 配列)`
  >  `explode(分割文字, 対象文字列)`
- 回答

  > `function lens(array $arr){ return explode(" ", implode(" ", $arr)); }`

Answer (score 0):

質問者です。多数の親切な回答ありがとうございます。

なるほど、"a fat man" をそのまま explode しても思った通りの結果が得られないけれど、lens() の中でいったん全体を implode することにより explode しやすくなるわけですね。
納得しました！
提出期限が明日 (9日) の午前11時だったのですが、なんとか間に合いそうです。ありがとうございました。